# Do Google Maps Flash API Markers fire an event when added to the stage?

Tags: google-maps, apache-flex, events, google-maps-markers

With the Google Maps Flash API, I want to add an event listener which fires when the Marker is added to the Map using map.addOverlay();  Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is not fired, though it seems logical. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever wonders about this again and misses what I missed, the answer is to use a custom marker Sprite, and attach the ADDED_TO_STAGE listener to the sprite rather than the Marker.